# On local-to-global theorem of $\mathrm{CD}^*(K,N)$ spaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

In the 2010 JFA paper *"Localization and tensorization properties of the curvature-dimension condition for metric measure spaces"* ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.2116), [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jfa.2010.03.024)), the authors used Theorem 5.1 to prove Theorem 7.10 without verifying the additional condition of Theorem 5.1. Namely, the authors have not verified for the covering spaces that $P_\infty(M,d,m)$ is a geodesic. Does this condition hold naturally?